# How to match multiple field in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb

Im trying to match forum_id with several different forum_id's, something like forum_id = 5,7,12,43,63,78

I currently have this code:

```
SELECT topic_title, topic_id, forum_id 
FROM $MYSQL_TOPIC 
WHERE topic_title 
LIKE '%%%s%%' 
    AND forum_id = 5 
LIMIT 50
```

(using mysql_real_escape_string and sprintf)

I tried:

```
forum_id = 5 OR 7
forum_id = 5|7
forum_id = 5 AND 7
forum_id = 5 & 7
```

But none of them will match them all and therefore search though them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

forum_id IN (5,7,12,43,63,78)

Comment: I new the commas would have something todo with it :P Thanks. Do you have a link to where I can read up some more on this 'IN' command? (it's rather a common word and google doesn't like common words :P )